# How can I use loop to update formula for forward selection

Tags: r, list, loops, formula

Good afternoon.

I am constructing loops for forward variable selection. At each step, I am sequentially adding one more terms in the dynlm regression and see which variable among explanatory variables yields the best in terms of maximizing rsquared. Since I have 100 explanatory variables, I have 100 models at most, and want to store residuals of each model so that I can compare which one of 100 models has the lowest AIC, BIC (by hand)

So far What I've accomplished is

```
### M0 (Null Model)
fm0 <- tr.y.nm[,1]~L(tr.y.nm[,1],1:4) #AR(4) model

r0 <- summary(dynlm(fm))$r.squared

### loop to choose M1 ~ M100 with forward selection
fml <- vector("list", 100)

r <- rep(0, 100) 

ssr <- rep(0,100)

rr <- matrix(c(1:100, 1:100), nrow=100,ncol=100) # 100 by 100

x <- rep(0,100) # index to indicate which regressor should be added when selecting best model

### M1
for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
  fml[[1]] <- update(fm0, .~. + L(tr.x.nm[,i], 0:1), evaluate=F)
  model <- dynlm(fml[[1]])
  rr[i,1] <- summary(model)$r.squared
}
x[1] <- which.max(rr[,1])
ssr[1] <- sum(model$resid^2, na.rm=T)

### M2
for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
  fm <- fml[[1]]
  fml[[2]] <- update(fm, .~. + L(tr.x.nm[,x[[1]]], 0:1), evaluate=F)
  model <- dynlm(fml[[2]])
  rr[i,2] <- summary(model)$r.squared
}
x[2] <- which.max(rr[,2])
ssr[2] <- sum(model$resid^2, na.rm=T)


### M3 
for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
  fm <- fml[[2]]
  fml[[3]] <- update(fm, .~. + L(tr.x.nm[,x[[2]]], 0:1), evaluate=F)
  model <- dynlm(fml[[3]])
  rr[i,3] <- summary(model)$r.squared
}
x[3] <- which.max(rr[,3])
ssr[3] <- sum(model$resid^2, na.rm=T)

# M4
for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
  fm <- fml[[3]]
  fml[[4]] <- update(fm, .~. + L(tr.x.nm[,x[[3]]], 0:1), evaluate=F)
  model <- dynlm(fml[[4]])
  rr[i,4] <- summary(model)$r.squared
  }
x[4] <- which.max(rr[,4])
ssr[4] <- sum(model$resid^2, na.rm=T)
```

fml is a list of 100, which I want to store formulas that will be used at each model.

e.g. > head(fml)

```
[[1]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1)

[[2]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
L(tr.x.nm[, x[[1]]], 0:1)

[[3]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
L(tr.x.nm[, x[[1]]], 0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[, x[[2]]], 0:1)

[[4]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
L(tr.x.nm[, x[[1]]], 0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[, x[[2]]], 0:1) + L(tr.x.nm[, 
x[[3]]], 0:1)
```

Considering this, since M2 ~ M100 model is adding one more term from M1~M99, respectively
I'd like to use loop something like the follow

```
    for (j in 2:100) {
     for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
       fm <- fml[[j-1]]
       fml[[j]] <- update(fm, .~. + L(tr.x.nm[,x[j-1]], 0:1), evaluate=F)
       model <- dynlm(fml[[j]])
       rr[i,j] <- summary(model)$r.squared
       }
    x[j] <- which.max(rr[,j])
   }
```

However, j is not identified in the above loop and since 4th index, the output is the same as the previous one, not working.

```
> fml
[[1]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1)

[[2]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
    L(tr.x.nm[, x[j - 1]], 0:1)

[[3]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
    L(tr.x.nm[, x[j - 1]], 0:1)

[[4]]
tr.y.nm[, 1] ~ L(tr.y.nm[, 1], 1:4) + L(tr.x.nm[, i], 0:1) + 
    L(tr.x.nm[, x[j - 1]], 0:1)
```

I guess indexing with j is not working, and don't know why. How can I index list with letter j whose value is defined before?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I succeeded in running the loop but it takes too long for the loop to complete. I believe sapply or lappy will be more efficient but dont know how to modify my code.

```
for (j in 2:100){
  for (i in 1:ncol(tr.x.nm)){
    fm <- update(fm0,.~.+L(tr.x.nm[,i], 0:1))
    scope <- paste0("L(tr.x.nm[,x[", 1:(j-1), "]],0:1)")
    fit<-fml[[j]]<- update.formula(fm, paste(".~. +", paste(scope, collapse="+")))
    model <- dynlm(fit)
    rr[i,j] <- summary(model)$r.squared
    }
  x[j] <- which.max(rr[,j])
  ssr[j] <-sum(model$resid^2, na.rm=T)
}
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], and read [ask], [answer], and their linked pages. You're misusing an answer, they're not for continuations of your question. Possibly you should have edited your original question and added this, but showing additional examples of what you tried that don't work isn't necessary.